# How to pass cookie to response expressjs?

Tags: node.js, express

I need to pass

> authCookie

to express response, I use technic JSONP to bypass CORS by google, but i don't know how to pass cookie to response. so client browser can get that cookie. the end result is direct google drive link with cookie. currently only pass direct link but the cookie null. i don't know.

client html

```
<video id="video-player" controls></video>
<script>
  const videoPlayer = document.getElementById('video-player');

  (async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/video');

    videoPlayer.src = await response.text();
  })();
</script>
```

Server

```
const express = require('express');
const htmlParser = require('node-html-parser');
const { parse }  = htmlParser;
const cors = require('cors');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;

app.get('/video', cors(), async (req, ress) => {    

    const response = await fetch('https://drive.google.com/uc?id=17OunL0rN- 
                                   7jrsNGjznQTqnB_z7xfsgKK&export=download', { redirect: 'manual' });

    const dom = parse(await response.text());

    const url = 'https://drive.google.com' + dom.querySelector('#uc-download-link')._attrs.href;

    const resCookie = await response.headers.get('set-cookie').split(';');

    const downloadCookie = resCookie[0];
    const nidCookie = resCookie[6].split(',')[1];

    const reqCookie = downloadCookie + ';' + nidCookie;

    let options = {
        headers: {
            cookie: reqCookie
        },
        redirect: 'manual'
    };

    const res = await fetch(url, options);

    const re = await fetch(await res.headers.get('location'), {redirect: 'manual'});

    const authCookie = await re.headers.get('set-cookie').split(';')[0];

    const r = await fetch(await re.headers.get('location'), { headers: { cookie: nidCookie }, redirect: 'manual' });

    const data = await fetch(await r.headers.get('location'), { headers: { cookie: authCookie}, redirect: 'manual'});

    ress.send(await r.headers.get('location'));
});

app.listen(port , () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening on ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use res.cookie(name, value) to set cookies with express. You can read more about it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/express-js-res-cookie-function/).

Comment: if the cookie AUTH_8632qh6ci45d3udksnrs31dgab4ghphl_nonce=hkifuhv9l3p40. i set it `res.cookie('AUTH_8632qh6ci45d3udksnrs31dgab4ghphl_nonce', 'hkifuhv9l3p40');`?